# Does deleting a Tumblr account lose tracking of questions asked on other people's tumblogs?

Tags: tumblr

If you delete your Tumblr account does it delete the questions you have posted on someone's ask box if they haven't seen it yet?

I deleted my tumblr because I was useless at it. I still like to check out blogs I liked because I like their edits, GIFs etc. Before I deleted my tumblr I placed an ask in someone's ask box and I really need to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it. Most likely the link to your profile will be disassociated but the question itself will not.

It's possible the user skipped over your question (maybe it was asked several time before).

Some Tumblr users tend to answer new non-duplicate questions.